# How do I use the accessibility tags of an HTMLElement?

Tags: typescript, dom

I'm new to typescript and I'm trying to figure out how to use the ARIA tags of HTMLElements. I already attempted to use an interface that extends on elements like so:

```
interface HTMLAriaElement extends HTMLElement {
    ariaValueMax: number;
    ariaValueMin: number;
    ariaValueNow: number;
}
```

However I still cannot assign my element to be a HTMLAriaElement. In javascript I could just modify the key `document.getElementById("somid").ariaValueNow`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so i solved my problem now (I think) with a class with custom get and set parameters that access the attributes property of my HTMLElement

```
class HTMLAriaElement extends HTMLElement {
    get ariaValueMax(): string { return this.getAttribute("aria-valuemax"); }
    get ariaValueMin(): string { return this.getAttribute("aria-valuemin"); }
    get ariaValueNow(): string { return this.getAttribute("aria-valuenow"); }
    set ariaValueMax(value: string) { this.setAttribute("aria-valuemax", value); }
    set ariaValueMin(value: string) { this.setAttribute("aria-valuemin", value); }
    set ariaValueNow(value: string) { this.setAttribute("aria-valuenow", value); }
    set ariaValueMaxNum(value: number) { this.setAttribute("aria-valuemax", value.toString()); }
    set ariaValueMinNum(value: number) { this.setAttribute("aria-valuemin", value.toString()); }
    set ariaValueNowNum(value: number) { this.setAttribute("aria-valuenow", value.toString()); }
}
```

Additionally I added setters that accept numbers like the DOM function does as well.